# What is this low growing plant with trifoliate leaves?

Tags: identification

[image]

This plant started growing in my flower garden out of nowhere and I hope that it is not poison ivy. Can anyone identify the low growing plant below the lily?

Comment: It's not poison.

Comment: There are some good comparison pictures here http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/which-of-these-if-any-are-poison-ivy

Comment: where do you live? is it cultivated or a weed, have you ever seen it flower, does it have any sort of smell... anything to go on?

Comment: If you can see any flowers that will provide a positive key to identify the plant

Comment: hi kevinsky...I'll get on it soon, I've got company coming for dinner.

Answer (score 4):

Could be *Aegopodium podagraria* [Ground elder / Bishop's weed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegopodium_podagraria)
There's a [lot of leaf variation in the species](https://www.google.com/search?q=ground%20elder&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=w9i&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=PCm0U_qUE4KXqAb75YCQAQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1165&bih=590).
If it's not exactly where you want it, it's a weed you want to deal with, as it's pretty good at crowding other plants out.

Answer (score 3):

[Two leafed toothwort](https://gobotany.newenglandwild.org/species/cardamine/diphylla/?pile=alternate-remaining-non-monocots)How about Cardamine diphyla, Two leafed Toothwort...?

Comment: Can you tell us the key identification points that lead to this plant?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the UK, so I've never actually seen poison oak or poison ivy - at first I thought this might be ground elder, but on closer inspection, and after doing some research, I'm now more convinced it's ground cover poison ivy rather than ground elder. The other two types of poison ivy or poison oak are vines and the leaves are not like this at all and obviously, they climb. This one doesn't. I can't think of any other plant it might be... as I understand it, this form of poison ivy deposits its toxin on surrounding surface areas, such as rocks and probably your fence.  Were it not for that, I'd suggest leaving it to see what it does, but in the circumstances, I'd be inclined to seek out whatever herbicide is available locally in order to kill it off without touching it. This answer assumes you live in a part of the USA where ground ivy is endemic. The following is a video called Poison Oak A Survival Guide - it shows what appears to be this form of poison ivy towards the end - deals first with the vine types.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipwER-ZbIuI

Comment: No poison ivy has such a long stem between the lateral leaflets and the main leaf stem.

Comment: @jmusser; what plant is it then?

Comment: i can see many trifoliate plants this does not match, but if I knew the answer, I would post  it. I've been dealing with poison ivy since I was a kid.

Comment: @jmusser - well perhaps I'm worrying unnecessarily - I'd be much happier if this plant could be identified, and I can't identify it, which is why I considered the possibility it might be poison ivy - which as I've said, is not something I've seen because, thank heavens, we don't have it here.